# Previous Window Focus / Electron

Tags: electron

Currently scratching my head on a tough one. I'm just starting with electron and so far so good. However, when the window gets hidden (it's a popup showing with a shortcut, that goes away when you press enter), I'd like to give the focus back to the previous window.

I'm using Mac, and the menu bar shows my previous app's name so it looks like the focus is given back to the app, but not entirely since the window is not selected.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your code look like? Are you calling `win.show()`?

Answer (score 18):

For Linux:
I found `browserWindow.hide()` correctly restores focus.

For Windows:
`browserWindow.minimize()` correctly restores focus.

For Mac:
`app.hide()` correctly restores focus. Note: calling `app.hide()` unfortunately hides all windows. There is no known way of keeping some windows open without hiding all with `app.hide()`.

This works both on Mac, Linux and Windows:

```
hide() {
    this.window.minimize();
    this.window.hide();
    if (process.platform == "darwin") this.app.hide()
}

show() {
    this.window.show();
    this.window.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just released on Github an Electron test app called [Popup Window](https://github.com/Mikaeru69/popup-window) which shows how to correctly give the focus back to the previous window. It is a streamlined version of one of my previous projects, and macOS only. I ran into the exact same problem you have, and I kind of remember that I solved it by hiding the app instead of the window, and handling the window blur event to actually hide it...

HTH...

**main.js**:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, ipcMain } = require ('electron');
let mainWindow = null;
function onAppReady ()
{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow
    (
        {
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            show: false,
            frame: false
        }
    );
    mainWindow.loadURL (`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    mainWindow.once ('closed', () => { mainWindow = null; });
    mainWindow.on ('blur', () => { mainWindow.hide (); });
    globalShortcut.register ("CommandOrControl+Alt+P", () => { mainWindow.show (); });
    ipcMain.on ('dismiss', () => { app.hide (); });
}
app.once ('ready', onAppReady);
app.once ('window-all-closed', () => { app.quit (); });
app.dock.hide ();
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**renderer.js**:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require ('electron');
document.addEventListener
(
    'keydown',
    (event) =>
    {
        if (event.key === 'Enter')
        {
            event.preventDefault ();
            ipcRenderer.send ('dismiss');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Hiding the app itself was the way to go. Brilliant, you just made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this worked for me:

```
mainWindow.on('blur', () => app.hide())
```

I use `mainWindow.hide()` to hide the app, and adding `app.hide()` on the blur listener returns the focus to the last used application.

Answer (score 1):

**Go on with my solution if you don't want to see app as minimized and hide its icon from the taskbar and gain focus for the previous window on hide.**

On Windows 11, previously focused window gains focus when the current window is minimized. So, my solution would work for you if you want to hide taskbar icon and make previous window gain focus (tested only on Windows 11 and macOS Ventura for a single window app):

```
hide() {
  if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    // Hides the window
    this.searchWindow.hide();
    // Make other windows to gain focus
    app.hide();
  } else {
    // On Windows 11, previously active window gain focus when the current window is minimized
    this.searchWindow.minimize();
    // Then we call hide to hide app from the taskbar
    this.searchWindow.hide();
  }
}

show() {
  this.window.show();
  this.window.restore();
}
```